# doctrine insert do not see foreign key field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO service (title, code, price, deleted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["asdf", "234", "234", 0]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

There is one more field in the entity `$serviceCategory`, which references service_category_id field.

Why is it not in insert operator?

I assume it should look like `INSERT INTO service (title, code, price, deleted, service_category_id) ....`

Here is yml orm:

```
Service:
    type: entity
    table: service
    id:
        id:
          type: integer
          generator: {strategy: AUTO}
    fields:
        title:
          type: string
          length: 255
        code:
          type: string
          length: 50
        price:
          type: decimal
          precision: 12
          scale: 2
        deleted:
          type: boolean
    ManyToOne:
        serviceCategoryId:
            targetEntity: ServiceCategory
            joinColumn:
                name: service_category_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Here is entity (only props):

```
class Service {
    /**
     * @var integer
     */

    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $deleted = false;

    protected $serviceCategoryId;

}
```

Comment: paste your relation, coz that looks like one to many relation and error can be checked after looking at the relation

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you have one more field "serviceCategory" in "service" table which is referenced to another table, you are not passing the value of this field. You will have to pass correct value of this value and make sure passing value must be the value of referenced table primary key value.

Comment: it is ManyToOne between Service entity and ServiceCategory entity. It passes correctly as ServiceCategoryId field of Service entity and contains ServiceCategory object.